# UPDATE with aggregate function and SELECT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to write a SQL instruction which update my database stock product quantity related to aggregate number of all delivers and orders.

```
UPDATE tbl_Product 
SET tbl_Product.Quantity = Q.Quantity
FROM 
    tbl_Product 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT tbl_Order.IdProduct, 
        SUM(tbl_Delivery.Quantity)-SUM(tbl_Order.Quantity) AS Quantity 
        FROM 
            tbl_Order
            INNER JOIN 
            tbl_Delivery 
                ON tbl_Order.IdProduct = tbl_Delivery.IdProduct 
        GROUP BY tbl_Order.IdProduct
    ) as Q 
        ON Q.IdProduct = tbl_Product.IdProduct;
```

Got a syntax error.

Comment: Can you post your error statement?

Answer (score 3):

Access can be finicky with an `UPDATE` which uses a join.  In certain situations, it may complain that the query is read-only.  And since your `UPDATE` uses a join with a `GROUP BY`, that may happen here.

If it does, you can use `DSum` so Access will consider your query to be editable.  If *IdProduct* is numeric data type use this ...

```sql
UPDATE tbl_Product AS p 
SET p.Quantity = 
    DSum("Quantity", "tbl_Delivery", "IdProduct=" & p.IdProduct)
    - DSum("Quantity", "tbl_Order", "IdProduct=" & p.IdProduct)
```

But if it's text type, enclose those values in quotes for the third option to `DSum`.

```
UPDATE tbl_Product AS p 
SET p.Quantity = 
    DSum("Quantity", "tbl_Delivery", "IdProduct='" & p.IdProduct & "'")
    - DSum("Quantity", "tbl_Order", "IdProduct='" & p.IdProduct & "'")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tbl_Product  
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT tbl_Order.IdProduct, 
        SUM(tbl_Delivery.Quantity)-SUM(tbl_Order.Quantity) AS Quantity 
        FROM 
            tbl_Order
            INNER JOIN 
            tbl_Delivery 
                ON tbl_Order.IdProduct = tbl_Delivery.IdProduct 
        GROUP BY tbl_Order.IdProduct
    ) as Q 
        ON Q.IdProduct = tbl_Product.IdProduct   
        SET tbl_Product.Quantity = Q.Quantity
```

Remove `FROM` move the `SET` last.

Answer (score 1):

Access SQL does not support the syntax you are trying to use. The query

```sql
UPDATE foo
SET foo.thing = bar.thing
FROM
    foo
    INNER JOIN
    bar
        ON foo.ID = bar.ID
```

results in "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression."

The corresponding query in Access SQL would be

```sql
UPDATE 
    foo 
    INNER JOIN 
    bar 
        ON foo.ID = bar.ID 
SET foo.thing = bar.thing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a nickname to the table you are updating.  Here is your code with the subquery abstracted.  Does this help?

```
UPDATE P
SET P.Quantity = Q.Quantity
FROM tbl_Product P
INNER JOIN (...) as Q 
ON Q.IdProduct = P.IdProduct;
```