# How to Update Each Netstock Table Items Quantity in respect of Inward Table Item Quantity in same Database

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I'm doing a stock management project using VB6.0 and MS Access Database without Primary Key.

I'm fetching a problem when I tried to update `Netstock` Table during Transaction on `Inward` Table.

I tried with the following code but errors occurred. Kindly help & resolve the same:

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection 

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset 

con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\Database.mdb;" 
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

rs.Open "UPDATE Netstock SET Netstock.P_Qty = (SELECT Inward.Item, Inward.Category, Sum (Inward.P_Qty) From Inward GROUP BY Inward.Item, Inward.Category, Inward.Brand) Where Netstock.Item = Inward.Item AND Netstock.Category=Inward.Category AND Netstock.Brand=Inward.Brand;", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

rs.Open "Select * From Netstock;", con, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs
```

`Netstock` Table Before Entering Data in `Inward` Table, `P_Qty` is the Purchase/Inward Quantity:

[image]

`Inward` table; `P_Qty` is the Purchase/Inward Quantity:

[image]

Netstock Table should be like this after entering data in `Inward` Table:

[image]

Kindly note if any Updation/Edit/Change done on the Inward Table same must be effected on `Netstock` Table.

Comment: What errors? - edit question. Can't run an UPDATE action with a 'non-updatable' dataset. Aggregate query is not updatable.

Comment: Certainly can't SET a single field to the result of a query that has multiple fields. Usually, saving aggregate data is a bad idea - calculate when needed. If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UPDATE with aggregate function and SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204304/update-with-aggregate-function-and-select)