# Update table with inner join with an aggregate function with SQL statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two tables and I need to update first table with max value from second table

Table1

| item | value |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | value1 |
| item2 | value2 |

table2

| item | value |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | value1 |
| item1 | value2 |
| item2 | value... |

I use this SQL statement :

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN  " & _
"(SELECT table1.item, MAX(table2.value) AS maxvalue FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2  " & _ 
"ON table1.item = table2.item GROUP BY table1.item) AS t2  " & _
"ON t1.item = t2.item SET t1.value = t2.maxvalue "
```

I get an error

> Operation must use an updateable query

if I take out max function from statement, SQL will execute, but I need max value

Comment: Access does not allow UPDATE action when aggregate query is involved. Use DMax() domain aggregate function or VBA or don't save aggregate data. If it can be calculated for UPDATE it can be calculated when needed. Saving aggregate data is usually a bad idea. This is a common topic.

Comment: Code is hard to read if it's all on one line. Please format your code so it is easy to read. That also includes removing the quotes; as it is, it is not code, it is just a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UPDATE with aggregate function and SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204304/update-with-aggregate-function-and-select)

Comment: @June7 I don't think. It is not possible to mix SQL statement with DMAX or such aggregate functions

Comment: Can build a query object then VBA runs that.

Comment: I tried that, but if query object has an aggregate function it gives same error when join with table @june7

Comment: Not an aggregate function, a Domain Aggregate function - DMax(). However, my primary recommendation is to NOT save this calculated value to table at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow @june7 and yes, Access does not allow UPDATE action when aggregate query is involved.

I even tried to join table with recordset as well and that way is not possible also.

So one solution is to create temp table first and then update the first table.

So the solution for my question is:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT table1.item, Max(table2.value) AS maxvalue INTO tempTBL " & _
 "FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.item = table2.item" & _
 "GROUP BY table1.item " & _
 "ORDER BY table1.item"

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN tempTBL AS t2 " & _
  "ON t1.item = t2.item " & _
  "SET t1.value = t2.maxvalue "
```

Comment: That's not the only solution but it is a solution.

Comment: I suppose it isn't the only one, any other suggestion is welcome @June7. I'd like to learn about other options.

Comment: I mentioned options in my first comment above. This is a common topic.

Comment: this topic is quite usefully  [link](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html)